# Servlet : New session created for every request when cookie is disabled

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies, session-cookies

Below Code I am writing in Servlet and making request to this servlet from index.html.
Form index.html I pass key and value for the session to add in it.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session == null){
    session = request.getSession();
}

session.setAttribute(request.getParameter("key"), request.getParameter("val"));

Enumeration list = session.getAttributeNames();
while(list.hasMoreElements()){
    String k  = (String)list.nextElement();
    String v = (String)session.getAttribute(k);
    System.out.println(k +"\t\t"+v);
}
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("index.html"));
```

Above code works fine when cookie is enabled.

Knowingly I disabled Cookie and Running this code.
I was expecting that all the attributes and their values will be added. But I am getting only the last one. What I observed is every time new session is created and The URL with JESSIONID is also changed every time.

I tested this in Chrome and firefox also.

Please help me to check where I am making mistake

Thanks

Comment: How do you think that HTTP requests are associated with a session? HTTP is a stateless protocol, so if you want to keep state then the client needs to send something back -- either a cookie or something else, like a request parameter.

Comment: I am using encodeRedirectURL() method to add session id if cookies are disabled.

Comment: Right, but then how does the session ID get passed back on subsequent request? Perhaps you need to provide more information about the whole flow.

Comment: When I call encodeRedirectURL() method then JESSIONID is send with URL and that comes back with next request and this helps to know that this request is associated with previous one. So as per my knowledge new session must not be created, which is not in this case.

Comment: You say *"from index.html I pass key and value"*. That means that the page will send a request to the server with a URL that maps to your servlet. Since you haven't shared that url, let's call it `myServet.do`. That could then be a GET method with a URL like this: `myServet.do?key=foo&val=bar`. There is no `JSESSIONID` is that URL, so the server doesn't know what session it is, and creates a new one. What your page should have done, is to build a URL like this: `myServet.do?key=foo&val=bar&JSESSIONID=xxxx`, where `xxxx` is the value of the `JSESSIONID` query parameter to the `index.html` page.

Comment: @Andreas As you mention in comment I am doing the same way and you are saying correct.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with help from comment of @Andreas I did following changes

1. I changed index.html to index.jsp
2. instead of writing Servlet.do in form action I change it to response.encodeURL("Servlet.do").

Now in second and so on requests are sent with previous JESSIONID to server.

Thank you Andreas for your help.